# Jmeter Backend Listener groovy issues

Tags: regex, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to add a JMeter backend listener to my JMeter project so I can have all the metrics in real-time in Graphite. My tests run distributed on several nodes and I want to know the hostname in as part of the graphite path. I tried to incorporate JSR223 scripts, but those are not evaluated before the listeners start, so I used the `__groovy()` method for the `rootMetricsPrefix` field, like this:

```
${__groovy(vars.get(vars.get("environment")+".graphiteprefix"))}.server.
${__groovy(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
.replaceAll(/^([^.]*).*$/){m,host->return host})}.
myappbucket.jmeter.
```

The first part gets the variable with the name "environment" to get the root prefix for the environment ("test", "load", etc). The seconds `__groovy()` script should get the first part of the hostname. It works if I add it as a JSR223 sampler (to test it), but if I try to use it as a variable, I get the following error:

```
Script13.groovy: 1: expecting '}', found '' @ line 1, column 67.
   me().replaceAll(/^(^\.).*$/){m
                                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:121) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> If a function parameter contains a comma, then **be sure to escape this with "\",** otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter. For example:
>
> ```
> ${__time(EEE\, d MMM yyyy)}
> ```

So you need to escape the comma between `m` and `host`

```
${__groovy(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() .replaceAll(/^(^\.).*$/){m\,host->return host})}. myappbucket.jmeter.
```

Also be aware of [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) and [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions, they provide a little bit easier way of getting the hostname and IP address of the JMeter Engine. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more comprehensive information on JMeter Functions

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. The escape of the comma was the issue. Thank you for pointing out the built in methods. I only am not sure they will not add domains to it like: 'hostname.mydomain.com'. And I want to prevent I get buckets with the mydomain.com in graphite. The groovy function now works perfectly.